# How to prevent inbound packet flood?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

This question is about how to deal with inbound messages in the application.

For example, application is able to process only one message at a time, and is not ready to accept more messages (through callback) until some specific time. Or more specific case - what will happen if broker will try delivering more messages to the client that client can physically hold (e.g. free allocatable RAM restrictions)?

What is the best way for implementation in this case?

Right now I am performing `mosquitto_loop()` manually. I see I can do `mosquitto_loop_read()` when ready to receive message, and `mosquitto_loop_write()` when ready to send message (e.g. after publish). But I am unsure because receiving messages, as well as publishing messages, involve both “read operations” and “write operations” (e.g. for publish send data and then receive PUBACK). What “read operations” means in `mosquitto_loop_read()` - perform logical read from the topic (which involves sending and receiving packets), or perform physical receiving only?

Next, how do I control how many messages I receive using `mosquitto_loop_read()` or `mosquitto_loop()`? Is it something about max_packets argument? Why it is “currently unused” as there’s clear use case for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special.

If you run the loop normally it will only handle one message at a time as long as you don't do any hand off to a separate thread in the message callback.

`mosquitto_loop()` will call the message callback for each incoming message and block until it returns.

Now if you can't process messages on average as quickly as they arrive you have a problem, but if it's just short bursts the messages should back up in the broker (you need to look at the max in flight message settings and probably use better than QOS 0)

Comment: Is there any proof in the documentation/standard that single `mosquitto_loop()` will collect only one message at a time, and will not loop inside itself if there're more messages from broker until there will be no more incoming messages? If it is not explicitly in there, then it may change in the future... and architecture will stop working properly.

Comment: Any change of that magnitude would include a major version number bump and documentation of a breaking change. (plus it's easy enough to test, just stick a println + sleep in the message callback)

Comment: It will be a breaking change if it was documented to be this way. If it just appears working this way right now, but not documented, will not be a formal change at all. That's why we would better look into docs... did you see any documenting this?

Comment: Proof is always in the code, not the documentation. If you don't believe what @hardlib is saying then read the code.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake. I must be talking about **specification**.

Comment: The MQTT spec doesn't care as long as the client respects the publish handshake for higher QOS messages. It's perfectly possible to write a compliant client that handles messages in parallel as well as one that does it sequentially, it's just that most of the early (and libmosquitto is early and if I was writing anything new i'd be using Paho) are sequential.

Comment: Section of the spec: http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718105 (include Non normative comment on message ordering and in-flight messages)